# How to write variables on csv with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have images in a folder.I want my script to scan every pics and take their mean and variance value and add them to csv.So in csv I will have 2 column name like Mean and Variance. Every pic will have mean and variance value.
This is part my code,I didnt fill important part datas on csv only header here and I want datas from images come into csv. How can i fix the problem.

Basically, example I have 100 pics in a folder.I want scan folder for every pic.I want take every pics mean and variance value and write it to csv.I dont know how can I describe it well come on.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import glob
import argparse
import csv

header = [
            "Mean",
            "Variance",
    ]
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-d","--dataset",required = True,help = "path to input dataset of images")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

for imagePath in glob.glob(args["dataset"] + "/*png"):
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath,0)
    dataMean=np.mean(img,axis=(0,1))
    dataVar=np.var(img,axis=(0,1))


    with open("data.csv", "wt", newline="") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
            writer.writerow(i for i in header)
```

Comment: What's the problem?  You haven't described the current output of the code.  As written, this code doesn't even execute. The code is indented improperly.  Read the [mcve] guidelines and make a working example of the problem.

Comment: try this it might help you out https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/working-csv-files

Comment: I think you might have a problem with writer.writerow(i for i in header) if you change it to just writer.writerow(header) it might do the trick

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your problem you should clarify it but if it is what I think it is, then this might fix your issue

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import glob
import argparse
import csv

header = [
            "Mean",
            "Variance",
    ]
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d","--dataset",required = True,help = "path to input dataset of images")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

with open("data.csv", "wt", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(header)

    for imagePath in glob.glob(args["dataset"] + "/*png"):
        img = cv2.imread(imagePath,0)
        dataMean=np.mean(img,axis=(0,1))
        dataVar=np.var(img,axis=(0,1))



        writer.writerow([dataMean,dataVar])
file.close()
```

Comment: I am sorry about it that I couldnt tell what was my real problem for real. But you solved it with smart way thanks a lot